# Why can't we satisfy F# static member constraints with type extensions?

Tags: f#, generic-constraints

I'd like to be able to extend types from other libraries with static methods to enable generic arithmetic. Take, for example, the newly minted SIMD-friendly fixed-size `VectorN` types from Microsoft. They define `Zero`, they define `(+)`, they define `(/)`, but I can't use `Array.average` on them because they don't define `DivideByInt`, which I'd be happy to:

```
open System.Numerics
type Vector2f with 
  static member DivideByInt (v:Vector2f) (i:int) = v / Vector2f(single i, single i)
let bigArray : Vector2f[] = readABigFile()
printf "the average is %A" (Array.average bigArray)
```

But it won't let me compile, complaining

```
error FS0001: The type 'Vector2f' does not support the operator 'DivideByInt'
```

Why does this limitation exist in the F# compiler?

(Edit: essentially the same question was asked [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681142/static-extension-methods-supporting-member-constraints).)

Comment: I suspect that `DivideByInt` needs to be an operator rather than a function.  Maybe try either defining an operator, or I think `op_DivideByInt` might work.

Comment: `DivideByInt` isn't a valid name for an operator in F#

Comment: Does doing `DivideByInt (v:Vector2f,i:int)` (tuple form) work?  I have got a minimal example with type extensions that works.

Comment: Looking at the source will show the constraints you need to satisfy: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/array.fsi

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not possible. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681142/static-extension-methods-supporting-member-constraints

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not currently possible to define an operator overload in a type extension. There is an [F# language user voice item](http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5695277-allow-the-addition-of-operators-in-type-extensions) for this (with quite a lot of votes) and so this is something that might change in future versions of F# (I think it would be great addition that fits nicely with the F# design).

If you absolutely need something like this today, you can either create a lightweight wrapper for your type that adds the operators, or you can use a (somewhat scary) trick that lets you hide the standard operator with a new overloaded one. The following question has both examples: [Global operator overloading in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682432/global-operator-overloading-in-f)