# Inline function and type extension

Tags: f#, inline

Consider I have two different *library* types:

```
type Foo = { foo : string }
type Bar = { bar : int32 }
```

I want to implement generic function `zoo` that will work for either `Foo` or `Bar` instances. **And I cannot change `Foo` and `Bar` because they are part of library code.**

Here's my first attempt using type extensions and inline function as explained [here](http://withouttheloop.com/articles/2014-10-21-fsharp-adhoc-polymorphism/):

```
// Library.fs
module Library

type Foo = { foo : string }
type Bar = { bar : int32 }

// Program.fs
type Foo with
    static member zoo (f : Foo) = "foo"

type Bar with
    static member zoo (b : Bar) = "bar"

let inline zoo (x : ^t) =
    (^t : (static member zoo : ^t -> string) x)

let f = zoo { foo = "1" } // error FS0001: The type 'Foo' does not support the operator 'zoo'
```

Why don't inline function definition relies on type extensions? How could I solve my problem without changing of the initial `Foo` and `Bar` type definitions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use method overload.

The problem with extension methods is that they are not taken into account when [solving member constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681142/static-extension-methods-supporting-member-constraints) .

So you can use method overload, as shown already in your own answer or you can go further and create an inline generic function by using an intermediate type and an intermediate method (in this case an operator for simplicity) to do the trick:

```
type T = T with
    static member ($) (T, x:Foo) = "foo"
    static member ($) (T, x:Bar) = "bar"

let inline zoo x = T $ x

let f = zoo { foo = "1" }
```

Here you have [more details](http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net/typeclasses-for-fsharp/) about how this works.

Be aware that this function will be inlined, so for instance you won't be able to call it from C#, if this is required don't use a function, use simple and standard method overload.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I could get so far is

```
type Ext =
    static member zoo (f : Foo) = "foo"
    static member zoo (b : Bar) = "bar"

let f = Ext.zoo { foo = "1" } // "foo"
let b = Ext.zoo { bar = 2 } // "bar"
```

It is not the best and not very generic solution but at least it works.