# Error on Extension Methods when Inlining

Tags: f#

I want to extend some system types and later use them via inlining

```
type System.String with  
    member this.foo n = this + "!" + n 

type System.Boolean with  
    member this.foo n = sprintf "%A!%A" this n
```

Now I call these extension methods

```
let x = "foo".foo "bar"
let y = true.foo "bar"
```

which gives me this

```
- val x : System.String = "foobar"
- val y : string = "true!"bar""
```

All fine and dandy - but now I want to wrap the call to `.foo` into an inline function

```
let inline foo n v = (^T : (member foo : ^N  -> ^S) v, n)
let z = foo "bar" "baz"
```

Only now I get a compiler error telling me that

```
> The type 'string' does not support the operator 'foo':
```

well ... it does!

Can somebody explain whats going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extension methods are not taken into account in static member constraints (possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913955/inline-function-and-type-extension/32914220#32914220)) and this is a general problem when you want to implement generic code using member constraints and make it work also with already defined or primitive types.

See the [user voice](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5695277-allow-the-addition-of-operators-in-type-extensions) request, also the workarounds mentioned [here](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5666323-operator-overloads-problem-in-f) and [Don Syme's explanation of why it's complicated to implement it in the F# compiler](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/2).

If you follow the links there you will see currently the way to workaround it basically involves creating an intermediate type and overloads for all the known types and a generic one for the extensions.

This is a very basic example of how to workaround it:

```
type Foo = Foo with
    static member ($) (Foo, this:int)    = fun (n:int) -> this + n 
    static member ($) (Foo, this:string) = fun n -> this + "!" + n 
    static member ($) (Foo, this:bool)   = fun n -> sprintf "%A!%A" this n 

let inline foo this n = (Foo $ this) n

//Now you can create your own types with its implementation of ($) Foo.

type MyType() =
    static member ($) (Foo, this) = 
        fun n -> printfn "You called foo on MyType with n = %A" n; MyType()

let x = foo "hello" "world"
let y = foo true "world"
let z = foo (MyType()) "world"
```

You can enhance it by adding an explicit generic overload for new types:

```
// define the extensions

type System.String with  
    member this.foo n = this + "!" + n 

type System.Boolean with  
    member this.foo n = sprintf "%A!%A" this n 

// Once finished with the extensions put them in a class
// where the first overload should be the generic version.
type Foo = Foo with
    static member inline ($) (Foo, this) = fun n -> (^T : (member foo : ^N -> ^S) this, n)
    static member ($) (Foo, this:string) = fun n -> this.foo n 
    static member ($) (Foo, this:bool)   = fun n -> this.foo n
    // Add other overloads
    static member ($) (Foo, this:int)    = fun n -> this + n 

let inline foo this n = (Foo $ this) n

//later you can define any type with foo
type MyType() =
    member this.foo n = printfn "You called foo on MyType with n = %A" n; MyType()

// and everything will work
let x = foo "hello" "world"
let y = foo true "world"
let z = foo (MyType()) "world"
```

You can further refine it by writing the static constraints by hand and using a member instead of an operator (see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607979/how-does-non-idiomatic-global-operator-overloading-work/37609744#37609744)),

At the end of the day you will end up with something like this [generic append](https://github.com/gusty/FsControl/blob/e19670cbf4683699884dd94a50ecd8e8797a4931/FsControl.Core/Monoid.fs#L59-124) function from FsControl.

Answer (score 2):

Statically resolved type constraints do not support extension methods. It's just not a feature of F#.

If you would like F# to gain support for higher-kinded polymorphism, you can [vote for it on user voice](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5664242-simulate-higher-kinded-polymorphism).