# F#: Inconsistent SRTP static extension method type matching

Tags: f#, constraints, extension-methods

I am trying to use `PrintfFormat` to type enforce resolution of parsers and it initially appeared to work for `int` but then same approach for `string` did not work... while float did work, so I thought was Value/Ref type issue but then tried `bool` and that didn't work like String.

`int` & `float` work, `string` & `bool` do not!?

(ParseApply methods are dummy implementations for now)

```ml
    type System.String  with static member inline ParseApply (path:string) (fn: string -> ^b) : ^b = fn ""
    type System.Int32   with static member inline ParseApply (path:string) (fn: int   -> ^b) : ^b = fn 0
    type System.Double  with static member inline ParseApply (path:string) (fn: float -> ^b) : ^b = fn 0.
    type System.Boolean with static member inline ParseApply (path:string) (fn: bool -> ^b) : ^b = fn true

    let inline parser (fmt:PrintfFormat< ^a -> ^b,_,_,^b>) (fn:^a -> ^b) (v:string) : ^b 
        when ^a : (static member ParseApply: string -> (^a -> ^b) -> ^b) =
        (^a : (static member ParseApply: string -> (^a -> ^b) -> ^b)(v,fn))

    let inline patternTest (fmt:PrintfFormat< ^a -> Action< ^T>,_,_,Action< ^T>>) (fn:^a -> Action< ^T>) v : Action< ^T> = parser fmt fn v

    let parseFn1 = patternTest "adfadf%i" (fun v -> printfn "%i" v; Unchecked.defaultof<Action<unit>> ) // works
    let parseFn2 = patternTest "adf%s245" (fun v -> printfn "%s" v; Unchecked.defaultof<Action<unit>> ) // ERROR
    let parseFn3 = patternTest "adfadf%f" (fun v -> printfn "%f" v; Unchecked.defaultof<Action<unit>> ) // works
    let parseFn4 = patternTest "adfadf%b" (fun v -> printfn "%b" v; Unchecked.defaultof<Action<unit>> ) // ERROR
```

The error I get on `result2` function format string input is `The type 'string' does not support the operator 'ParseApply'`, similarly, `result4` error is `The type 'bool' does not support the operator 'ParseApply'`.

I don't know why there is this inconsistency, is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Thank @ChesterHusk, good to know where to monitor

Comment: Thanks @Gustavo for providing a work around, your solution is working nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @ChesterHusk said, at the moment extensions are not visible to trait calls.

See also [Error on Extension Methods when Inlining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071645/error-on-extension-methods-when-inlining/38071927#38071927)

At the moment, the way to make it work is using an intermediate class with an operator-like trait call (operators normally look into their own class and in user defined classes).

```
open System

type T = T with
    static member inline ($) (T, _:string) : _ ->_ -> ^b = fun (path:string) (fn: string -> ^b)-> fn ""
    static member inline ($) (T, _:int)    : _ ->_ -> ^b = fun (path:string) (fn: int   -> ^b) -> fn 0
    static member inline ($) (T, _:float)  : _ ->_ -> ^b = fun (path:string) (fn: float -> ^b) -> fn 0.
    static member inline ($) (T, _:bool)   : _ ->_ -> ^b = fun (path:string) (fn: bool -> ^b)  -> fn true

let inline parser (fmt:PrintfFormat< ^a -> ^b,_,_,^b>) (fn:^a -> ^b) (v:string) : ^b = (T $  Unchecked.defaultof< ^a> ) v fn

let inline patternTest (fmt:PrintfFormat< ^a -> Action< ^T>,_,_,Action< ^T>>) (fn:^a -> Action< ^T>) v : Action< ^T> = parser fmt fn v

let parseFn1 = parser "adfadf%i" (fun v -> printfn "%i" v; Unchecked.defaultof<int>)
let parseFn2 = parser "adf%s245" (fun v -> printfn "%s" v; Unchecked.defaultof<string>)
let parseFn3 = parser "adfadf%f" (fun v -> printfn "%f" v; Unchecked.defaultof<float>)
let parseFn4 = parser "adfadf%b" (fun v -> printfn "%b" v; Unchecked.defaultof<bool>)
```

This can be written with named methods by replicating the way operators trait call are desugared.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is still an open gap in the F# compiler, ie that Extension Members are not visible to type constraints.  There's a WIP PR [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/3582) that bridges the gap.